# Exchange 2010 - Auto-forwarded email not arriving at destination (20/40% missing)

Tags: email, exchange-2010, mail-forwarding

Good morning,

we have a weird issue with Auto Forwarding emails from Exchange 2010.

Little background information first, I work for a daughter-company, lets say @bla-daughter.com. Our head office is @bla.com

When customers send a purchase order, they send it to: info@bla.com, which is a distribution list. That sends it to user1@bla.com and user2@bla.com. Those then auto forward to user1@bla-daughter.com and user2@bla-daughter.com.

Everyone still with me :)

Ok, now the emails arrive at user2@bla.com and user1@bla.com mailboxes, but between 20% and 40% doesnt arrive at user1@bla-daughter.com and user2@bla-daughter.com.

Example, I send 5 emails from my google account, 3 arrived. Boss send 5 from outlook.com, 4 arrived. Other guy send 5 from some Russian web based email, also 3 arrived.

To summarise the flow

Info@bla.com -(works)-> user1/user2@bla.com -(20/40% missing)-> user1/user2@bla-daughter.com

Now, we have confirmed the following
1. We get no error messages or refusal messages from the servers, not from Bla nor bla-daughter.com
2. Send 50+ test messages to info@bla.com, they all arrive in users mailboxes
3. Checked the junk mail for users at bla-daughter.com (also did Tracking Log Explorer, emails didnt arrive at @bla-daughter.com)

My supision, due to lack of error messages/bounce back messages, that not all emails are being forwarded. Is there a way to see if the exchange-server @bla.com actually forwarded the email?

Second, can anyone think of another point of failure that I have overlook.

I know, most ppl with go TL;DR, but let me know if you can think of something, or if you have additional questions, as I am stuck atm.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see if the exchange-server @bla.com actually
>   forwarded the email?

Sure.  One thing you need to state though is the flow of email from bla.com to bla-daughter.com.  Is the mail flow internal connectors?  Disparate organizations entirely as if they were two separate companies and email goes back out over the internet?

Check the message tracking logs in the Exchange server or turn up the Transport logging detail and check those logs.

http://exchangepedia.com/2007/05/exchange-server-2007-logging-smtp-protocol-activity.html

You can follow that guide ^ if necessary.

If you don't see logs showing that bla.com's mail servers are at least sending it outbound...then it isn't being forwarded.  In which case you need to check and make sure the rules, etc. on the mailboxes are accurate.

Finally, you need to consider simply adding the users at bla-daughter.com directly to the original distro list instead of using forwarding.  Create contacts for them in Exchange on bla.com and add those contacts to the distro list.  That way you don't have to deal with the "forwarding" rules you've setup.